# Present view from delegate modally in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I cannot seem to find this anywhere online.  I have an add button in one of my views and I have hooked it up to an `IBAction` method called `add`.  In my storyboard, I have created a view that has a form all set up on it.  I have assigned a class to that view in the storyboard as well.  That class is called `AddItemViewController`.

I am trying to present this view modally and then set the delegate to the view that called the AddItemViewController.  However, all I get is an empty UITableViewController that shows up.  Here is my code that I'm trying to use:

```
- (IBAction)add {
    AddItemViewController *addItem = [[AddItemViewController alloc] init];
    addItem.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:addItem animated:YES];
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?  Why does it just show an empty table and not the view controller that I set up in the storyboard?

Here is the code from the AddItemViewController:

```
@interface AddItemViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *note;

- (void)save:(id)sender;
- (void)cancel:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation AddItemViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

    }

    - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
        DbHandler *db = [[DbHandler alloc] init];
        [db executeUpdate:self.note];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
@end
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the AddItemViewController class?

Comment: Added the AddItemViewController code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `AddItemViewController` inherits from UITableViewController, not UIViewController, so it makes sense that a UITableViewController is showing up.

You should initiate the `AddItemViewController` like this:

`AddItemViewController *addItem = [[AddItemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddItemViewController"];`